# StreamSubscription not resuming when the app comes back to foreground

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have a stream that should run endlessly in a screen (it yields a value each 5 seconds). It must be paused when the app goes to background and resumed when the app comes back to foreground. The problem is that it doesn't actually resume after being paused. The relevant parts of my code are the following:

```
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver{
  StreamSubscription _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await _initStreamAndSubscribe(); // inits a stream s and sets
                                       // _subscription = s.listen(...)  
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState lifecycleState) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(lifecycleState);
    if (lifecycleState != AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      _subscription?.pause();
    } else {
      _subscription?.resume();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _subscription?.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong here already or the problem is probably in some other part of my code?

**Edit 1**

I'd like to add that I call `_subscription?.pause()` and `_subscription?.resume()` in other place on the same class, namely when I need to go to another screen and then come back. In this case, the stream is resumed with no problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed that `_subscription?.pause()` and `_subscription?.resume()` are always called twice each. My bet would be that, if one pauses a stream twice, resuming it twice does not actually resume it. Anyways, I replaced `_subscription?.pause()` with

```
if (!(_subscriptiton?.isPaused ?? true)) {
  _subscriptiton?.pause();
}
```

to avoid pausing it twice. It worked.